# Calculate $\int^{1/2}_0\int^{1-x}_x (x+y)^9(x-y)^9 \, dy \, dx$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How can I find the following integral:

$$\int^{1/2}_0 \int^{1-x}_x (x+y)^9(x-y)^9 \, dy \, dx $$

My thoughts:

Can we possibly convert this to spherical or use change of variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

according to the shape of the area of integration and the shape of the function that is under integral, the easiest answer is to define variables $u=x+y$ and $v=x-y$then we have:
$$\frac{1}{J}=\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}=\begin{vmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{vmatrix}\Rightarrow |J|=\frac{1}{2}$$
and the borders of the area of integration are $u=-v,u=1,v=0$ just draw the shape of the problem to understand this part.then:
$$\int^{1/2}_0 \int^{1-x}_x (x+y)^9(x-y)^9 \, dy \, dx=\int^{0}_{-1}\int^1_{-v} \frac{1}{2}u^9v^9\,du\,dv=\frac{-1}{400}$$

---

**Edit:** to answer the question asked in the comments:
why did I use $\frac{1}{|J|}$?
consider the analog situation for a 1-D integral where we have to use `change of variables` method:
$$\int\frac{x\,dx}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}$$
we have $u=x^2\Rightarrow du=2x\,dx$
meaning that we have $u$ as a function of $x$ so we can calculate $du=\frac{du}{dx}dx$ but in order to substitute $dx$ in the original integral we write $du=2x\,dx\Rightarrow dx=\frac{1}{2x}du$ which means that we need $dx=\frac{dx}{du}du$ to substitute in the original integral so
**In a 1-D integral we have $u$ as a function of $x$ so we can calculate $\frac{du}{dx}$ but to substitute in the original integral we need $\frac{dx}{du}$**
here is the same situation:
to substitute in the original integral, we need:
$$dx\,dy=\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}du\,dv=|J|du\,dv$$
But most of the time we have $u$ and $v$ as a function of $x$ and $y$:
$$u=f(x,y),v=g(x,y)$$
so we can compute 
$$\frac{1}{|J|}=\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}$$

Comment: Does the definition of your new variables have something to do with an affine transformation?

Comment: @Khallil as you know we can use the method `change of variables` in 1-D integrals to calculate them easier  just like that we can use `change of variables` in a 2-D or 3-D integral. and the jacobi above defines the relationship between old variables and new ones. `change of variables` is just mapping from a space to another space just like the affine transformation is.

Comment: May I ask why you chose to define your variables in such a way?

Comment: @Khallil because I want to find a way to calculate the above integral easier. if you draw the borders of the original integral in the question you will see that it's a triangle sides $x+y=1,x-y=0,x=0$ also you have the terms $x-y,x+y$ in the function so you will deduce that choosing the variables this way will make both the function and the borders easier. **I should say that choosing the new variables is just a trick you will learn as much as you solve problem.practice makes perfect**

Comment: Thanks for the help, @sepideh!

Comment: @sepideh Why did you use 1/J?

Comment: @NadiaMarson I edited my answer to respond your question

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$(x+y)^9(x-y)^9=((x+y)(x-y))^9=(x^2-y^2)^9$$

Comment: Okay, so we can introduce an 'r here by saying that $(-(x^2+y^2))^9=(-r^2)^9=-r^{18}$. Right?

Comment: Okay I got that much. Now what do I do next?

Comment: Actually, the expression is $(x^2-y^2)^9$. Now you can use binomial expansion of  $(x^2-y^2)^9$ so that all the terms are separated in powers of $x$ & $y$ then integrating all, first w.r.t. $y$ then w.r.t. $x$  It can be done but the procedure/expansion will be lengthy.

Comment: It doesn't seem efficient or intuitive. Just a hammering of algebra.

Answer (score 1):

How about a change of variable like $u=x+y, v=x-y$?

The Jacobian is $-\frac 12$, and the area of integration is the triangle bounded by the lines $x=y, x+y=1, x=0$

This translates as: $v$ varies from $v=0$ to $ v=u$ for the inner integral, and $u=0$ to $u=1$ for the outer integral.

Therefore we evaluate $$\int_{u=0}^{u=1}\int_{v=0}^{v=u}u^9v^9(-\frac 12)dvdu$$

The final answer is $-\frac{1}{400}$

Comment: Yes. Actually I was wanting something in this direction. Can you please show me this step-by-step if you don't mind?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
u & = x+y \\
v & = x-y
\end{align}
$$
du\,dv = \left|\frac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}\right|\,dx\,dy = 2\,dx\,dy
$$

\begin{align}
& \int^{1/2}_0 \int^{1-x}_x (x+y)^9(x-y)^9 \, dy \, dx \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^1 \left( \int_{u-1}^0  u^9 v^9 2\,dv \right) \,du \\[10pt]
= {} & \int_0^1 u^9 \frac{(-(u-1)^{10})} 5  \, du 
\end{align}